# How to write a procedure to execute a .txt file

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have multiple txt files on my local system. Each of which contains a table creation query. These are huge tables so I have a separate file for each table.
I need to write a procedure/function which will execute each of these .txt files and create the tables in the tablespace.

How can I do this? 
The server is Oracle11g and I am using SQL Developer to access it.

Comment: Unless these files are on the database server's file system (or accessible to the database server file system), a stored procedure cannot access them.  Why are you looking for a stored procedure in the first place, though?  Can you just have a client side SQL*Plus script that runs each script?

Comment: Thank you Justin. I am new at this so dont know how to do this, I thought procedure is the way to go. How do I write a SQL*Plus script ?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the full script path preceded by @ on SQL Developer and execute it. Ex.

```
@'C:\script dir\script1.sql'
@'C:\script dir\script2.sql'
@'C:\script dir\script3.sql'
```

Select all lines and press execute button. There's no need to write a complex procedure to access the file system and deploy the scripts. On SQL*Plus, you only need to paste each line and press enter, or put all script calls on a wrapper script and call just the one

```
@'C:\script dir\callAllScripts.sql'
```

If I absolutely had to develop an automatic deploy tool for a system, I'd store the scripts on local FS or on any shared network folder the server had access to, and make a loop on shell or batch scripts calling sqlplus to execute the scripts the same way I've described above.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I created a batch file calling all the other files and stored all on the shared folder.--Thanks a lot